# Sharing code between Blueprint?

Tags: flask, share, blueprint

How do you share code between Blueprints in Flask?
What structure do you use?

Do you create separate class? If yes how do you pass app or db instances.

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on your code. If this is some kind of helper functions or classes, you may put it into package near your `app`. If shared code depends on context, perhaps you need to review project structure. As noted by miso in the previous answer:

> The documentation of Flask is pretty good. So take a look.

Especially in the section on [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/blueprints/).

But if you sure that structure of your project is good, and you still have a lot of shared code- then, perhaps, it may be usefull to create standalone library or [Flask-extension](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/extensiondev/).

Anyway, it all depends on your code.

Answer (score 1):

To access from any module to an application instance, Flask provides the global object [`current_app`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.current_app), which maintains a reference of one application instance in the [current context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/appcontext/). This is useful if you want to have various instances of your application running together with different configurations. To use it:

```
from flask import current_app
```

From the Flask docs

> The application context is created and destroyed as necessary. It
>   never moves between threads and it will not be shared between
>   requests. As such it is the **perfect place to store database connection**
>   information and other things.

The documentation of Flask is pretty good. So take a look.

Comment: I will try that... but I was thinking more of sharing code, rather than state. And probably passing "db" or other stuff as part of the call (may be).